# Add class to rightmost div(s) on responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a bunch of floating divs. Depending on the screen size will certain divs form the rightmost column. Is there any way to add a class only to these divs, at the edge of the screen?

On a wider screen it looks like this:

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div class="rightDiv">4</div>
<div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div class="rightDiv">8</div>
```

On a smaller screen:

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div class="rightDiv">3</div>
<div>4</div><div>5</div><div class="rightDiv">6</div>
<div>7</div><div>8</div>
```

Preferably having the last div of the bottom row untouched if it's not at the edge of the screen but as the last child it's easy to handle.

Comment: Can you control the breakpoint and you know when your layout switches from 4 columns to 3 columns? You need the class just to apply a style?

Comment: @Fabrizios question is on point. so many ways to do this, it all depends on what you aim to accomplish

Comment: No I can't, it's entirely up to the client's settings. These DIVs are like thumbnails, there are hover effects (full size image out of screen) as well as unneccessary margins etc. Each of these problems have existing solutions one by one, I just thought applying a class would make things much easier and my code shorter.